# Contractible space of maps between Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces, 2

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, mapping-space

Let $G$ and $H$ be torsion abelian groups.
Are the following are equivalent:

1. $\mathrm{Hom}(G, H) = 0$
2. $\mathrm{map}_*( K(G, m), K(H,n)) \sim *$ for all $n, m\geq 1$

?

Clearly (2) implies (1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we have $Hom(\mathbb{Z}/n,\mathbb{Z})=0$ but there is a nontrivial Bockstein $K(\mathbb{Z}/n,1)\to K(\mathbb{Z},2)$.

For finite abelian groups we have (1) iff (2) iff ($|G|$ and $|H|$ are coprime).

Comment: Of course.  I'll edit the question so that it makes more sense.

Comment: I see that I haven't gotten around to editing the question, and I don't quite remember what I was driving at; and since you did answer the question, you get the cigar.